# How to make detective transition for the section in the viewport (go to provided link to watch the video)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

[image]

I have a webpage with multiple sections with unique id's associated with it. I want to show the number with little line in the background (line is bit large for the active section with number and small line for other sections) for the current section with transition from one section to another.

Comment: Jappreet, it is not super clear what you have tried to make this happen, or where this current example even comes from? What are you asking for help with _exactly_?

Comment: Hi @JonathanKempf, If you have watch the video, I think you'll understand clearly. I haven't done so much work on transitions and I'm not sure how to describe the problem.
There is one webpage with multiple sections, each section have unique id and i want to show it as per the video. Please help me with it if you understood

Comment: Jappreet, what have you tried? Please paste some code so that people would be able to actually narrow down a solution. The current surface area for a solution is too wide with the limited information you have pasted here.

Comment: @JonathanKempf, I've tried it on jsfiddle but don't think I'm heading in the right direction. That's why I haven't pasted the code.

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then update your question. This is too open to opinion-based answers without any code to review.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide me, where should I start from. I'll try it and then update my query.
If you know related solutions, please update it here.